# Jquery pop ups not working in IE 7, 8, 9

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I have something similar to the fiddle below. The issue is that some pop-ups work and some don't in *IE 7 8 9*.

Those that do not work seem to be the ones where the PNG, although not visible, overlaps the `a.trigger`.

This is not an issue in Chrome. I am just wondering if any one had come across this.

[pop-up example](http://jsfiddle.net/M2vew/13/)

Comment: Probably won't work in IE because you are missing a semicolon on this line - `$("div.pop-up").css({'display':'block','opacity':'0'})`

Comment: Also missing a semicolon on the closing brackets of your `hover` function...

Comment: I have changed that and it doesn't fix the issue, I can get the pop up to work on all the anchors in IE but the two problem ones only work right on the edge of the a.trigger, its like the display:block isn't working right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `div.pop-up`s are set on CSS as `display:none;`, while your jQuery tries to show them by animating their `opacity` to `1` on `hover`.

Setting something's opacity to 1 does not in any way affect CSS `display:none`. You'll have to change how you're hiding / showing your `div`s.

Comment: The reason this was done is that the pop ups need to fall back to a css hover if javascript is disabled. Do you have a method that can provide both?

Comment: I removed the display none and has mad no difference in IE

Comment: I'm thinking that if you really want to go the `opacity` route, try using `.fadeIn()` and `.fadeOut()` instead of the low-level `.animate()` method.

Comment: I dont want or need to go the opacity route, I am quite new to all this and I was given some help on here to build this out. Now I am kind of stuck andcan't figure out what to change

Comment: I know what causes it in IE, the a.trigger that are overlapped by the pop up are the ones that don't work. Even when the pop up isn't visable

Comment: I was kind of hoping to get more constructive answers than this.

Comment: If you know that the problem is the overlap, **then you know how to fix it**. One idea is to remove the overlapping element from where it is when it's not shown, and just position it when showing. Another is to leverage z-indices. Yet another is to prevent the overlap in the first place --- the way it looks when the tooltip is shown, I'm sure you can structure your markup differently to prevent the overlap anyway.

Comment: Okay thank you, I will try positioning the pop ups out the way when there not visable

Comment: I just have one last question, If you look at my code how would I position the pop up off screen and bring it back, I tried adding positioning to div.pop-up to push it off screen but it didn't work.